# ng build run command is failing with the Error with Angular.json is not found

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Tried to update Angular cli,it's not working at all [Error Image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLt1f.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLt1f.png).Please Guid Me -how to resolve this

```
@angular-devkit/core         0.5.6
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.5.6
@angular/cli                 6.0.0-rc.4
@ngtools/json-schema         1.1.0
@schematics/angular          0.5.6
@schematics/update           0.5.6
rxjs                         5.5.10
typescript                   2.8.3
webpack                      2.7.0
```

Comment: Have you followed update.angular.io steps while migrating? Stable 6.0 is released. Please check update portal once.

Comment: With v 6, Angular team updated angular-cli.json to angular.json. You may miss some step in the upgrade process.

Comment: how to roll it back @RukshanDangalla or how to update this -Please let me know the steps.Its very confusing in angular portal

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.0-rc.4",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "del-cli": "^0.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  }

Comment: None of the commands ng-serve ,npm start or npm build run is working

Comment: https://update.angular.io/ refer this this can help

Comment: Don't you have a source control manager ? Just revert to your last commit and follow the upgrade guide mentionned above

Answer (score 0):

@Sarvesh Gupta Can you try this.

Ensure you don't use extends OnInit, or use extends with any lifecycle event. Instead use implements lifecycle event

During the Update
If you use animations in your application, you should import BrowserAnimationsModule from @angular/platform-browser/animations in your App NgModule.

Rename your template tags to ng-template

If you rely on the date, currency, decimal, or percent pipes, in 5 you will see minor changes to the format. For applications using locales other than en-us you will need to import it and optionally locale_extended_fr from   @angular/common/i18n_data/locale_fr and registerLocaleData(local).

Make sure you are using Node 8 or later

Update your Angular CLI globally and locally, and migrate the configuration to the new angular.json format by running the following:

**npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install @angular/cli
ng update @angular/cli**

Update all of your Angular framework packages to v6, and the correct version of RxJS and TypeScript.

**ng update @angular/core**

After the update, TypeScript and RxJS will more accurately flow types across your application, which may expose existing errors in your application's typings

Use ng update or your normal package manager tools to identify and update other dependencies.

After the Update
Remove deprecated RxJS 6 features using rxjs-tslint auto update rules

For most applications this will mean running the following two commands:

**npm install -g rxjs-tslint
rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json**